# How to use the same instance of an object

Tags: java, singleton, instance

I wonder if there is a simple way to use the same instance of an object in Java.

I have a `MySerial` class, used to communicate via serial (I'm using RXTX library, but it's not relevant to the problem).

Let's assume that:

- there is a GUI with a button "Connect", which on click it instantiates a MySerial object and it connects to a serial port;
- there is a Performer class that is driven by a Thread that every two seconds send a message via serial (if a connection is available);

I want that the same instance of `MySerial` used in the GUI is the same used in the `Performer` class. The problem is that `Performer` and GUI don't know each other: it's like they are two separated programs, so I can't just pass `MySerial` to constructors.

I tried playing around using SingleTon and ClassLoader, but none of it worked.

Any advice?

Comment: Why doesn't the Singleton pattern fullfill your requirements? Will there be more instances of MySerial shared between the GUI and Performer?

Comment: Question: Performer and GUI are in the separated process? If you are using Windows, then are there two process `java.exe` in the TaskManager? In that case, `Singleton` or `enum` don't working.

Comment: @esej no just one instance. I guess I'm doing something wrong (probably two different processes instead of one). I'll make some test.

Comment: @PaulVargas Yes, two different processes. I'll try to see if I can get it working in the same process.

Comment: Ok tried with a single process: it's working like a charm. Thank you all very much

Answer (score 2):

Even though Singleton pattern will solve your problem - it's not something you should use very often(avoid it at all cost). **Why don't you simply send the reference to an object?** If it's too difficult, you probably have some problems with the architecture. Fix the architecture - don't avoid the problem with singleton patterns or you'll find yourself in a lot of mess!

Comment: For sure it's an architecture problem. To create Performers, I'm using a kind of "black box framework": I can't create performers by myself, but I have to use this "framework" that reads an XML configuration file to instantiate Performers. Anyway i think I was doing something wrong with SingleTon (read my comments upper). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the singleton pattern is what you need. it's rather simple to implement and should not make a problem (according to what you describe) For example:

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton instance;

    private MySingleton() {}

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MySingleton();
        return instance;
    }

    private String s = "hello";
    public String getString() {
        return s;
    }

}
```

From GUI / Performer:

```
String someString = MySingleton.getInstance().getString();
```

Comment: How about using an enum for the singleton?

Comment: That exactly what I was doing, but in two different processes. It should work now

Comment: Ok tried with a single process: it's working like a charm. Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

If you have each instance in its own `JVM` (one `java.exe` in *TaskManager* in Windows), you can't share the same instance of `MySerial`. You need **init** in the **same process** the two applications. The you can use a `enum` o `Singleton`.

```
public class Main {
    enum MySerial { ... }
    public static void main(String... args) {
       Performer.main(args);
       GUI.main(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok tried with a single process: it's working like a charm. Thank you all very much